# Analysing dump: how to interpret Windbg command "!heap -srch <address>" output?

Tags: windows, windbg, dump

I'm analysing a dump of a Windows process, the dump has been created using `procdump`.

I'm wondering what some collections (`CMap`) of `CAlarm` objects look like (a `CAlarm` object is created by my own program).

In order to do this, I'm launching following commands:

1) What is the address of the type I'm interested in?

```
x /2 *!*CMap*CAlarm*`vftable*
00000001`3fc7b840 <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const * __ptr64,CAlarm * __ptr64,CAlarm * __ptr64>::`vftable'
```

2) Which objects are of this particular type?

```
!heap -srch 00000001`3fc7b840
skipping searching 00000000014d6660 allocation of size 000000000002ee08 greater than 0000000000010000
skipping searching 00000000003fdf00 allocation of size 0000000000025ff0 greater than 0000000000010000
skipping searching 000000000042bf00 allocation of size 000000000001fff0 greater than 0000000000010000
=> no results, so let's do something else:

!heap -srch `3fc7b840
This gives a lot of objects, something like:
_HEAP @ 920000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    00000000009214a0 0002 0002  [00]   00000000009214b0    00010 - (busy)
...
_HEAP @ 860000
          HEAP_ENTRY Size Prev Flags            UserPtr UserSize - state
    00000000008612e0 00ce 00ae  [00]   00000000008612f0    00cd0 - (free)
```

Let's now use the `UserPtr` entry (let's start with the last one):

```
0:000> dt <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const *,CAlarm *,CAlarm *> 00000000008612f0
 +0x000 __VFN_table : 0x00000000`00860158 
 +0x008 m_pHashTable     : 0x00000000`00860158  -> 0x00000000`008612f0 CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const *,CAlarm *,CAlarm *>::CAssoc
 +0x010 m_nHashTableSize : 0
 +0x018 m_nCount         : 0n0
 +0x020 m_pFreeList      : (null) 
 +0x028 m_pBlocks        : (null) 
 +0x030 m_nBlockSize     : 0n0
```

This looks reasonable, but is it correct? That's quite doubtful, when looking at another entry:

```
0:000> dt <application_name>!CMap<ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >,wchar_t const *,CAlarm *,CAlarm *> 00000000009214b0
 +0x000 __VFN_table : (null) 
 +0x008 m_pHashTable     : (null) 
 +0x010 m_nHashTableSize : 0
 +0x018 m_nCount         : 0n1153117455832760832
 +0x020 m_pFreeList      : (null) 
 +0x028 m_pBlocks        : (null) 
 +0x030 m_nBlockSize     : 0n0
```

=> No way my CMap has to many elements.

It looks like I'm using the `x /2` result in a wrong way as input for the `!heap -srch` command. Does anybody know what's the right way to do this?

Comment: Both hits are false positives. Notice that the `Size`s are `0002` and `00ce` but your object's size is `0038`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. The title "How does it work?" But the text doesn't ask about how it works, it's "What is the right way of doing this?" Which is still not the same as "How do I interpret the output?"

Comment: @RaymondChen: you're right. I've adapted the title accordingly.

Comment: The root cause of the problem is that your initial search found no results. So the thing you want is not in the dump. You then issued a less specific search, which will consist entirely of false positives. UserPtr and UserSize and state are the values visible to the program. The other values are internal to the heap manager and aren't that useful to app developers.

Comment: Are you sure `!heap -srch` is the correct command in first place? Aren't you looking for `!heap -flt s <size>`?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: you might be right that I'm not using the right command, but the issue is the following: I'm using a script, written for detecting memory leaks (heap_stat.py) I know the type of objects, which are using huge amounts of memory. Now I'd like to know which are the objects, belonging to that type. I might indeed search for those objects, based on the size, but I'm afraid that the size might not be unique, hence my idea to use the `!heap -srch` feature. Or do you see other means to solve my issue?

Comment: Ok, the size is not unique. That's true. I am not too familiar with C++. Is the vftable stored for each and every C++ object that is created? I doubt that. In C#, that's the case: every C# object is stored with its method table, so you can exactly enumerate the complete heap and identify all objects and their types (`!dumpheap`). I have never seen this for C++. If that would be possible, there would certainly be a similar command that could list all objects.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: nevertheless my original question still stays open: how can I use the `!heap -srch` feature?